# Can't differenciate the code on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os
import time
print "Ping atmak istediginiz sitenin ip'sini yaziniz"
site = raw_input ("Site IP= ")
print "Basladi : %s" % time.ctime()
os.system("ping 'site' ")
time.sleep( 6 )
print "Bitti: %s" % time.ctime()
```

When I run the script it pings 'site'. Not the IP that I supply with `raw_input`. How can I solve it? When I open it on the command line and enter the website's IP, it pings the 'site' word. But  I wanna ping the IP.

Help me please. I've tried using `"""`, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

use `os.system("ping {}".format(site))`

Answer (score 0):

Your `os.system` call should read:

```
os.system("ping {}".format(site))
```

See the Python documentation for more information about [common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html?highlight=string#module-string).

Comment: Invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import os
import time
print "Ping atmak istediginiz sitenin ip'sini yaziniz"
site = raw_input ("Site IP= ")
print "Basladi : %s" % time.ctime()
cmd = "ping " + site
os.system(cmd) 
time.sleep( 6 )
print "Bitti: %s" % time.ctime()
```